# btrfs send error: not on mount point

Tags: btrfs

I followed the steps from this site https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Incremental_Backup and created a backup on my external disk. But if I want to make the incremental backup I got an strange error.

```
btrfs subvolume snapshot -r /home /home-bak-new
```

Everything went fine so far.
After that I have this subvolumes:

```
sudo btrfs subvolume list /
ID 256 gen 77392 top level 5 path @
ID 371 gen 77392 top level 5 path @home
ID 434 gen 75414 top level 256 path home-bak
D 435 gen 77395 top level 256 path home-bak-new
```

home-bak is an older snapshot of my home subvolume.
Than I did this:

```
sudo btrfs send -p /home-bak /home-bak-new | sudo btrfs receive /mnt/backup/backup
```

... and got this strange error:

```
ERROR: not on mount point: /home
ERROR: empty stream is not considered valid
```

I don't know what the problem is, both snapshots are readonly.
My Distribution is a Manjaro.